# Django signal database change on template

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, real-time, django-postgresql

I'm building a GPS Tracking System using Django, i should have a grid on my template that display real time information of cars (position,vitesse, temperature...). GPS send data to Postgres DataBase via a module that parse Data and saved it in specific table. What i need is how to make my Web App display data in real time? (when i row inserted in Db, how can i display it in grid)

i tried this package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-db-signals/0.1.1, but my DataParser is external from my django web app, it work independently from other side

Comment: You can make the parser go through the ORM and then use post-save signals. This might be a lot of work, though.

Comment: looks like you need some PUB/SUB mechanism